# What is the criteria for "killed X creatures with one blow"?

Tags: diablo-iii

I seem to occasionally get the "killed X creatures with one blow" bonus, even though I decidedly did not kill X creatures with a single shot. It sometimes happened to me when using "channeled" skills (such as rapid fire) and sometimes even using multiple regular attacks.

What is the exact condition for receiving the bonus? And if it's really "X creatures killed under Y seconds", then what is Y?

Comment: One blow counts as Barbarian Cleave or Rapid fire skills, normal attacks *(that is even exist on D3? (jk))* does not count as one single blow. At least as far as I could test on the open beta. This is why is not so easy get the one blow 20 kills. You usually get 6 to 10 creatures killed with one blow.

Comment: @Michel I am certain that I've had multiple attacks counted as a single "blow" (e.g. more than one cleave).

Comment: strange, I know that cleave has a rune that after killing a target (or each attack, not sure) he makes an explosion. this is how I got tons of one blow kills. I got once, both (One blow and multiple creatures kills), first the One blow then the multiple kills. Following this logic, should not I only get one of theses two?

Comment: I found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4nh3aRJb7Sw&feature=player_embedded#!), really cool to study how this works. And you are right, he killed and got some One blow bonus using only berserker skill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my experience so far, you get Mighty Blow if you **kill 6 or more enemies under X seconds.**

I have not scientifically measured it, but **I think the X is between 0.5 and 1.**

It seems completely independent as to the source of the kill - a single skill activation, a channelled skill activation, multiple hits, traps - as long as it's >6 kills in <X seconds, you get the Mighty Blow bonus.

Comment: I think you are right, randomly I get some mighty blows with only monk Sweeping Wind active using no other skills.

Comment: Also, I've experienced a Mighty Blow from the explosion of the obese compound undeads (for example those found in the cathedral or in the waterway passage).

Answer (score 0):

From what I have observed, you receive the bonus as long as you keep doing actions that kills enemies without interruption (to move, for example).

Clicking on another creature to go and bash it is ok, but clicking on the ground to reposition yourself is not.

Comment: My experience disagrees - for instance, I just channeled a skill and did nothing else, and got the massacre bonus, but not the mighty blow one.

Answer (score -1):

You may think your multiple attacks were counted as one blow but they weren't. The only thing that could make it seem that way to you is the window of time between the end of the blow and the toast message that pops up on the screen.

There is enough time to attack a few times in there and it can look like it counted multiple attacks but it didn't.

One blow is 1 attack (even if that attack kills enemies at different times for whatever reason) or 1 continuous channel. Anything else simply looks like it counted multiple attacks when it actually didn't.