# Do channeled skills count as one attack?

Tags: diablo-iii

Mighty Blow grants bonus XP for killing multiple enemies with one attack.  Do channeled skills like Tempest Rush, Ray of Frost, and Rapid Fire count as a single attack for this purpose?

Comment: Curious about this as well. Particularly when it comes to witch doctor summons.

Comment: I've brought up a [meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4556/should-questions-about-xp-bonuses-on-diablo-3-all-be-lumped-together) about whether or not this should be closed as a dupe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get a Mighty Blow when you use a channeled skill, but only if you kill enough monsters fast enough. The fact that you use a channeled skill to kill enough monsters does not qualify for Mighty Blow unless you kill them quickly enough.

I'm pretty sure that, in general, Mighty Blow does not care at all on *how* you got the kills - from a single channeled skill, from an AoE attack, from a combination of mines and 2 different skills - it only cares about 6+ kills in a short enough timespan (about a second). So whether a skill is channeled or not has no impact here.

But either way I was able to 100% verify that Mighty Blow is obtainable from channeled skills, but only when you kill the monsters quickly enough.

Comment: Are you sure? Mighty Blow is "Kill X enemies in one hit."  That seems misleading if it works the way you describe.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot pretty sure from my experience, and also just tested it just now with Rapid Fire. Killed a whole bunch of creatures without letting go of my mouse but over a long-ish time span, and didn't get the bonus. Did get the massacre bonus, which means it was enough monsters

Comment: So maybe channeled skill count as one attack within a certain timeframe?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot I'm pretty sure that "mighty blow" does not care whether it's a single skill or a single channeled skill or 4 different skill. All it cares about is X kills in a Y time window, where Y is pretty short, around a second. I was able to achieve mighty blow with two different skills - when I killed quickly - and was unable to achieve it with a single channeled skill, when I killed slowly.

Comment: How can you be sure *one* of the skills didn't qualify for a Mighty Blow on it's own?

Comment: @OrigamiRobot it's a good point, I cannot be completely certain, next time I'll try to count :) however, regarding the question here - whether a channeled skill is enough for mighty blow - the answer is definitely no, from my first-hand experience.

Comment: well you can use a channeled skill to kill quickly too, so technically the answer is still yes, you can mighty blow with it :P

Comment: I'm 100% certain that it doesn't matter if you use more than one skill. I've recieved mighty blow for 8 enemies killed using a skill that has a maximum of four enemies it can hit.

Comment: I have gotten Mighty Blow from one long hold down of the Whirlwind button several times.

Answer (score 4):

Mighty Blow bonuses trigger off of sustained attacks *so long as* several monsters die within a very short span of time. The easiest way to test this is on the first Act IV boss, who spawns a ridiculous amount of minions - sustained attacks such as the Wizard's Disintegrate can and will activate Mighty Blow, but only measure across a brief period of time - usually about two or three 'ticks' of the ability, though it may differ depending on which is in use.

My computer's too terrible for video evidence, but here's a screenshot of Mighty Blow triggering from just Disintegrate on the aforementioned boss:

[image]

Comment: I've noted that mighty blow bonuses can also trigger off of passive damage reflect, such as the Wizard's Storm Armor, despite it not being an attack at all. It seems to be all about the short period of time, as opposed to any specific attack type.

Comment: Mighty Blow is not only about how long the attack takes - I've seen a 60+ kill mighty blow on a Locust Swarm, which took a significant amount of time to play out (it only jumps once or twice a second), so I think the "short period of time" is related to the channel.

Answer (score 3):

I have gotten the kill X monsters in one hit bonus experience while using Rapid Fire.  So at the very least, Rapid Fire counts as one attack.  The other 2 probably does as well.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, yes they do. For example the area-of-effect attack of the Barbarian allowed me toget up to 10 kills on nearby skeletons with a single activation, and thus a single blow.

Answer (score 1):

Sustained attacks seem to be exactly what the [Massacre](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49545/how-does-the-massacre-bonus-work) kill-streak bonus was designed for. Killing multiple enemies with de-facto different shots or attacks (even though they are of the same skill) and being rewarded with the Might Blow skill seems counter intuitive, since it's called Mighty **Blow** after all, and it does give some unfair advantage to players who regularly use these skills (although this doesn't really matter, it doesn't give a disadvantage to other classes) - but it still works.

To be more precise, in my tests I found that the only difference between Massacre and Mighty Blow seemed to be that all kills in Mighty Blow must result from one and the same attack of a certain skill, while Massacre can combine an arbitrary amount of skills. This results in sustained attacks of skills like Rapid Fire counting as one "blow".

Comment: From my experience, though, it is certainly possible to obtain mighty blow from more than one attack. Also see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63421/what-is-the-criteria-for-killed-x-creatures-with-one-blow#comment89988_63421

Answer (score 1):

Mighty blow requires you to kill at least six monsters in quick succession using a single skill.

It's very similar to the [massacre bonus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/49545/18830), except that massacre requires you to kill at least 10 enemies in quick succession using multiple skills.

Because it's based on kill timing and the use of a single skill **it does not matter** whether rapid-fire or channeled skills are implemented as a single attack or multiple attacks.